# OCR model for reading Captchas from Keras Author: A_K_Nain

Tags: python, keras, ocr, google-colaboratory, ctc

I was working for OCR model applied to word mnist dataset from Kaggle in colab. I was inspiring by the model from ocr captcha with LSTM and CTC layer authored by  A_K_Nain in Keras examples hosted in the site :https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/

It was working for me. but now I have a lot of problems in codind and decoding characters to and from number. And I tried to compilate the model in the site of ocring captcha and I found same problems.
Can anyone explain what is the problem and if there is anyway to fix the problem.

I think the problem is in the following code:

**Mapping characters to integers**

```
char_to_num = layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(characters), num_oov_indices=0, mask_token=None
)
```

**Mapping integers back to original characters**

```
num_to_char = layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)
```

which maybe present some problems in his function.

Answer (score 0):

Removing  `num_oov_indices=0` and  `mask_token=None` worked for me.

#### Mapping characters to integers

```
char_to_num = layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(characters))
```

#### Mapping integers back to original characters

```
num_to_char = layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(),invert=True
)
```

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/StringLookup) from tensor flow documentation.

#### Forward and inverse lookup pairs

This example demonstrates how to use the vocabulary of a standard lookup layer to create an inverse lookup layer.

```
data = tf.constant([["a", "c", "d"], ["d", "z", "b"]])
layer = StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
i_layer = StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab, invert=True)
int_data = layer(data)
i_layer(int_data)
```